# Is it possible to use the index of an array in a map block?

Tags: dictionary, raku

I would like to use the index of the array in a map routine. For example, this Raku code:

`raku -e 'my @a = "First", "Second", "Third", "First"; say @a.map({ "Index of $_ is: ;" })'`

prints:

`(Index of First is: ; Index of Second is: ; Index of Third is: ; Index of First is: ;)`

Would it be possible to get the index of the array, like:

`(Index of First is: 0; Index of Second is: 1; Index of Third is: 2; Index of First is: 3;)`

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean "Fourth" for the fourth element?

Comment: I used "first" on purpose (instead of "fourth") to indicate that this is an arbitrary name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is [`.kv`](https://docs.raku.org/type/List#routine_kv) to produce "keys" and values. For an array, the keys are the indexes 0, 1, 2...

```perl
 >>> my @a = "First", "Second", "Third", "First";
[First Second Third First]

>>> @a.kv
(0 First 1 Second 2 Third 3 First)
```

This is a flat sequence of length 2N; we can tell `map` to take 2 things at a time, either via an explicit signature:

```perl
>>> @a.kv.map(-> $index, $value { "Index of $value is $index;" })
(Index of First is 0; Index of Second is 1; Index of Third is 2; Index of First is 3;)
```

or via [placeholder](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#The_%5E_twigil) variables:

```perl
>>> @a.kv.map({ "Index of $^value is $^index;" })
(Index of First is 0; Index of Second is 1; Index of Third is 2; Index of First is 3;)
```

Since *index* comes lexicographically before *value*, it works out as in the previous explicit signature case, i.e., the same signature is produced for us behind the scenes. We can see this:

```
>>> &{ $^value, $^index }
-> $index, $value { #`(Block|140736965530488) ... }
```

Note that what matters is the Unicode order of variable names, not the order of appearance.

---

In the spirit of TIMTOWDI, some alternatives (IMO not better):

- Rely on the [anonymous scalar state variable $](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/state#The_$_variable) to produce a stream of 0, 1, 2...

```perl
# Limitation: generated anew per closure and per mention,
# so cannot use, e.g., in string interpolations with closure and more than once
>>> @a.map({ "Index of $_ is " ~ $++ ~ ";" })
(Index of First is 0; Index of Second is 1; Index of Third is 2; Index of First is 3;)
```

- Using [`.pairs`](https://docs.raku.org/type/List#routine_pairs), cousine of `.kv` to produce "key => value" pairs instead of a flat list

```perl
>>> @a.pairs
(0 => First 1 => Second 2 => Third 3 => First)

# Reach over .key & .value
>>> @a.pairs.map({ "Index of $_.value() is $_.key();" })
(Index of First is 0; Index of Second is 1; Index of Third is 2; Index of First is 3;)

# Unpack with signature
>>> @a.pairs.map(-> (:key($index), :$value) { "Index of $value is $index;" })
(Index of First is 0; Index of Second is 1; Index of Third is 2; Index of First is 3;)
```

- Instead of mapping the array's values themselves, we can map the keys of it:

```perl
# Array.keys produces 0, 1, 2...
>>> @a.keys.map({ "Index of @a[$_] is $_;" })
(Index of First is 0; Index of Second is 1; Index of Third is 2; Index of First is 3;)

# ^@a is equivalent to ^@a.elems === 0 ..^ @a.elems, i.e., 0, 1, 2... again
>>> ^@a .map({ "Index of @a[$_] is $_;" })
(Index of First is 0; Index of Second is 1; Index of Third is 2; Index of First is 3;)
```

This last one is the least idiomatic I think.

Answer (score 2):

Using `for` (and/or `given`) loops to get Array/index output:

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a = "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth";  \
            given @a.kv { .put };'
0 First 1 Second 2 Third 3 Fourth
```

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a = "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth";  \
            for @a.kv { .put };'
0
First
1
Second
2
Third
3
Fourth
```

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a = "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth";  \
            for @a.kv -> $k,$v { say $k => $v };'
0 => First
1 => Second
2 => Third
3 => Fourth
```

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a = "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth";  \
            for @a { put "Index of {$_.values} is " ~ $++ ~ ";" };'
Index of First is 0;
Index of Second is 1;
Index of Third is 2;
Index of Fourth is 3;
```

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a = "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth";  \
            for @a.kv -> $k,$v { put "Index of $v is $k;" };'
Index of First is 0;
Index of Second is 1;
Index of Third is 2;
Index of Fourth is 3;
```

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a = "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth";  \
            for @a.pairs { put "Index of {$_.value} is {$_.key};" };'
Index of First is 0;
Index of Second is 1;
Index of Third is 2;
Index of Fourth is 3;
```

---

If you've read this far, you're probably wondering how this relates to the original `map` question. The answer is simple: add an imperative `do` to the `for`/`given` loop, drop the `put`, and now you have the same (stringified) return, just as if you were using `map` instead:

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a = "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth";  \
            my @b = do for @a.pairs { "Index of {$_.value} is {$_.key};" };  \
            .put for @b;'
Index of First is 0;
Index of Second is 1;
Index of Third is 2;
Index of Fourth is 3;
```

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a = "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth";  \
            @a = do for @a.pairs { "Index of {$_.value} is {$_.key};" };  \
           .put for @a;'
Index of First is 0;
Index of Second is 1;
Index of Third is 2;
Index of Fourth is 3;
```

*Yet another trick in the Raku grab-bag of tricks!*

https://docs.raku.org/syntax/do%20%28statement%20prefix%29

HTH.